# How to prove that there's at least one of them to be multiple 5?

Tags: number-theory

how do we prove that if $a^2+b^2=c^2$, and they are all integers, there would be at least one of them to a multiple of 5.
What I did is to assume that none of them to be multiple of 5. So$$a=5p_1+r_1, b=5p_2+r_2, c=5p_3+r_3, 0<r<5$$.
By direct substitution back to the equation, we would have:
$$5(5p_1^2+2p_1r_1+5p_2^2+2p_2r_2-5p_3^2-2P_3r_3)=r_3^2-r_1^2-r_2^2$$.
Then, we can list all possible scennarios to show that for this equality to be held, there must be at least 1 r to be 0. I want to ask is there any quick way we can show $$r_3^2-r_1^2-r_2^2$$is a multipler of 5 unless one of them to be 0. Thank you.

Comment: **Hint :** Try all the cases according to the class of $a$, $b$, $c$ mod $5$.

Comment: I see. thank you. I am still quite confusing about modular arithmetic.. Haven't learnt it before

Comment: Please read Pythagorean Triples. One is always divisible by $5$ and one is always divisible by $3$.

Comment: One more you can go through - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154424/observations-on-integer-sided-right-triangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo $5$, all squares are in $\{-1,0,1\}$. The only ways two squares can add up to a third square modulo $5$ are
$$0+0=0$$
$$1+0=1$$
$$-1+0=-1$$
$$1+(-1)=0$$
There is a zero in all four possibilities. So in $a^2+b^2=c^2$, at least one variable is a multiple of $5$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But, how do we show that all squares are in {-1,0,1}, thank you.

Comment: @HenryCal Brute force.

Comment: I see. understood. That's much faster

Comment: are we saying about the squares of r or the squares of every integers. If for every integers...we can't actually brute force....?

Comment: @HenryCai Because we are taking modulo $5$, we only need to test for $5$ consecutive integers; the other integers will just repeat. Conventionally we'd take $0,1,2,3,4$ as the test integers.